# Getting component's innerHTML

Tags: angular

I have component `<app-code-viewer><b>This is code</b></app-code-viewer>`.
In it I want to fetch component's innerHTML - not parsed by angular: `<b>This is code</b>` a a string variable.

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by "not parsed by angular" exactly? From where do you want to fetch it? (Where is the code that fetches it in relation to where the HTML is?)

Comment: I've tried `ElementRef` but it gives me: 1. component's content (with <app-code-viewer> element), 2. with angular's special attributes (ex. `_ngcontent-c1`). Fetching code should be in `AppCodeViewer` class

Comment: There won't be a way to get it without `_ngcontent-c1` because that is what the HTML looks like in the DOM, and there is no other way than getting it from the DOM.

Comment: Angular changes html on compilation. So you cannot get it like it was in uncompiled state